# C++Builder: how to hide yellow line in UI?

Tags: c++builder

Please help - how to remove this yellow line in C++Builder: Community Edition? [image: Screenshot]

It's pretty distracting in this cozy dark interface :) I've googled this line, but failed to find.. And tried bunch of options, but failed to find this line.. :(

Comment: I would try to find it in color scheme options and change the color to what ever you like (or to the same color as background) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can *remove* the yellow bar, as it is integrated into the Code Editor.  However, you can *change* its color to mesh better with your dark theme, at least.

Per the [Code Editor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Code_Editor#Change_Bars) documentation:

> ### Change Bars
>
> The left margin of the Code Editor displays a green change bar to indicate lines that have not been changed in the current editing session. **A yellow change bar indicates that changes have been made since the last File > Save operation**.
>
> You can, however, customize the change bars to display in colors other than the default green and yellow. Select *Tools > Options > User Interface > Editor Options > Color*. In the **Element** drop-down menu, select **Modified Line** then change the foreground and the background colors.